# c# using declarations - more = good or bad?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

*edit* typos

Hi,

This is possibly a moronic question, but if it helps me follow best practice I don't care :P

Say I want to use classes & methods within the System.Data namespace... and also the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Is it better to pull both into play or just the parent, ie...

```
using System.Data
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

or just...

```
using System.Data
```

More importantly I guess, does it have ANY effect on the application - or is it just a matter of preference (declaring both the parent and child keeps the rest of the code neat and tidy, but is that at the detriment of the application's speed because its pulling in the whole parent namespace AND then a child?)

Hope thats not too much waffle

Comment: `using` doesn't behave like `#include` in C, where there can be a noticeable compilation performance hit from including unnecessary or repeated header files (though most header files would have 'include guards' specifically to avoid what you've described.)  In C#, `using` is purely a way to help the IDE and compiler resolve type names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't make *any* difference to the compiled code.

Personally I like to only have the ones that I'm using (no pun intended) but if you want to have 100 of them, it may slow down the compiler a smidge, but it won't change the compiled code (assuming there are no naming collisions, of course).

It's just a compile-time way of letting you write Z when you're talking about X.Y.Z... the compiler works out what you mean, and after that it's identical.

If you're going to use types from two different namespaces (and the hierarchy is largely illusional here) I would have both `using` directives, personally.

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems the majority of info on this points just to Intellisense slowing down if anything

Comment: @beardwizzle and flooded with stuff. I don't mind if it takes a moment, as if I need to know I'm already thinking about it, but good lord there are a mountain of classes out there. Both VS and Resharper can help you keep it clean (there is an add on that will let you remove and sort usings on save aside from resharper so it's not just for when you have that)

Answer (score 8):

Click `Organize->Remove Usings` and Visual Studio will tell you the correct answer.

Comment: This appears to have changed under VS 2012 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514115. The method that worked for me was _right-click anywhere inside the code editor, point to Organize Usings, and then click Remove Unused Usings._

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it has no effect on the application.  You can prove this by looking at the CIL code generated by the compiler.  All types are declared in CIL with their full canonical names.

Importing namespaces is just syntactical sugar to help you write shorter code.  In some cases, perhaps where you have a very large code file and are only referring to a type from a specific namespace a single time, you might choose *not* to import the namespace and instead use the fully-qualified name so it's clear to the developer where the type comes from.  Still, though, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Express what you mean and aim for concise, clear code - that's all that matters here. This has no effect on the application, just on you, your colleagues and your future workers brains.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever happens when write your type name and press `Ctrl + .`,`Enter` in VS.